# I can't parse a JSON with gson

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, gson, mapping

i have this part of my json
[POKEAPI get pokemons/sprite/version/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzBtX.png)

is from POKEAPI, the problem is in kotlin I can't use the '-' for creating a variable, for example: "var myvar-i = 0" and I need to create the variables exactly like the JSON for GSON mapping and the sprites in the JSON I need are like this

generation-i
generation-ii
etc..

in kotlin, I can't create variables with the '-'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncg1H.png)

someone help me, ¿How can I map that information in kotlin?

Comment: You can theoretically escape variable names using backticks: ``var `my-i` = 0`` but I'd still recommend using annotation for a custom serial name instead as this functionality exists mostly to solve compatibility issues with keyword conflicts in cross-language projects.

Comment: I guess that using maps rather than fields might be better for that API: if I understand how that API works, those names then appear as values for other payloads.  So I don't really think you should bother with mapping it right to fields instead of maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotation `@SerializedName`

In your case it would be something like:

```
class Versions {
    @SerializedName("generation-i")
    var generation1: Generationgame? = null
   ...
}
```

More about the annotation can be found in [the docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).